# when people go to my website it shows all my files and not the landing page of my website -mclosed

Tags: html

when I go to my website directory it [shows all my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVPc2.png) and not to my landing page, is there a way to fix this? I have tried everything even looked through the internet without any clear response. I am close to finishing my website I only need to resolve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Make it go to `/ar/home.html` instead of `/ar`?

Comment: im sorry whats the code for that? i used
 to know how to do it through php but i forgot

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you are not on the HTML file, but on the folder.

---

To fix this issue, you have to redirect yourself to the HTML landing page.

```
/ar/home.html
```

This should show your HTML landing page correctly rendered.

---

*Tip:* Normally, the main page is called `index.html` by convention. This can be helpful. For example, the *Live Server* extension on *Visual Studio Code* will automatically go to `index.html` if the file isn't specified. Other hosting services, like *GitHub Pages*, also do the same.

<sub>**None of the extensions, IDEs and hosting services listed above are sponsored!** They are just used for the sole purpose of examples.</sub>

---

In conclusion, you need to go to the HTML file, instead of the folder.